# apk con ubicacion en segundo plano permanente

Tags: apk

estoy creando una apk con expo en react native que envie la ubicacion hacia una api propia, lo cual lo hace, pero solo en primer plano, o con el emulador en segundo plano tambien, pero no lo realiza cuando creo la apk para instalar directo en el mobil, la verdad es que se poco de programacion y me ayudo mucho la ia, pero quede trabado en el punto que la app no envia ubicacion cuando se encuentra en segundo plano, adjunto el codigo

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, AppState } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

TaskManager.defineTask('locationTask', async ({ data, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log('Error en la tarea de ubicación en segundo plano:', error);
    return;
  }

  if (data) {
    const { locations } = data;
    // Actualizar la ubicación en la base de datos o realizar cualquier otra acción necesaria
    console.log('Ubicaciones actualizadas:', locations);
  }

  const taskResult = data ? 'success' : 'nodata';

  return taskResult;
});

const Ubicacionviaje = () => {
  const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState('');
  const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const requestLocationPermission = async () => {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        console.log('Permiso de ubicación denegado');
        return;
      }

      const isTaskRegistered = await TaskManager.isTaskRegisteredAsync('locationTask');
      if (!isTaskRegistered) {
        await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync('locationTask', {
          accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High,
          showsBackgroundLocationIndicator: true,
        });
      }
    };

    requestLocationPermission();

    return () => {
      Location.stopLocationUpdatesAsync('locationTask');
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateCoordinates = async () => {
      try {
        const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
        if (status !== 'granted') {
          console.log('Permiso de ubicación denegado');
          return;
        }
        
        const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync();
        const { latitude, longitude } = location.coords;
        setLatitude(latitude);
        setLongitude(longitude);
        console.log('Latitud: ' + latitude);
        console.log('Longitud: ' + longitude);
        autoExecute(latitude, longitude);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error al obtener la ubicación:', error);
      }
    };

    updateCoordinates();

    const intervalId = setInterval(updateCoordinates, 50000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);

  const autoExecute = (latitude, longitude) => {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        latitud: latitude,
        longitud: longitude,
      }),
    };

    fetch('https://phoenixtravels.ejemplo/api/ejemplo', requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((result) => console.log(result))
      .catch((error) => console.log('error', error));
  };

  const botonaparecer1 = () => {
    // Lógica para mostrar/ocultar el menú
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
      if (nextAppState === 'active') {
        console.log('La aplicación está en primer plano');
        Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync('locationTask', {
          accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High,
          showsBackgroundLocationIndicator: true,
        });
      } else {
        console.log('La aplicación está en segundo plano');
        // no detener ubicacionLocation.stopLocationUpdatesAsync('locationTask');
      }
    };

    AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);

    return () => {
      AppState.removeEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Ubicación de Viaje</Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Latitud: {latitude}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Longitud: {longitude}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={botonaparecer1}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Mostrar/Ocultar Menú</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <WebView  />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  button: {
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#2196F3',
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});

export default Ubicacionviaje;
```

y tambien la app.json

```js
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "popo",
    "slug": "popo",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#fffeee"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "permissions": [
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
      ],
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.dcampania.popo"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "cf9eb9c7-40c3-40d6-9ef1-ba4dbacf642d"
      }
    },
```

la verdad es que no se como seguir, si alguien es tan amable de darme una ayuda se lo agradecere